# is there a way to get the entire database design?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, view, schema

I am working on this database that was already created. i just got access to however i am not sure how all the individual tables are all linked to other tables, so i was wondering is there any tool or any query that will give me the over all database deign such as

[image]

Comment: You mean other than SSMS? You can create a new database diagram and add all of the tables. The relations will come along for the ride.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are tools that can perform a reverse engineering operation from database to relationship diagram.
DbVisualizer, Visio, Dot are just examples to do that.

Please note that the reverse engineering works on phisical relationships. So if there are logical relations that are not mapped to a FK you will not see that relation on the ER diagram.

Comment: logical relations?? can you please give me an example of when that would occur??

Comment: If the person who designed the database didn't add a FK. It can be also a correct design decision. Imagine you have a database where a table is populated from an external source that is not reliable at 100%. You can imagine to put a logical relationship between two tables, but you can't define a FK because sometimes it generate errors.

Comment: Another example of logical relationships: I work with a database where many of the tables have `ref_type` and `ref_num` fields for a single, optional relation to one of any of several other tables.